# Software to put company-specific info on the desktop

Tags: windows, osx

I need to place company specific info (phone numbers, reports etc.) on the desktop background of our company computers. It's dynamic data, so I need a quick way to change it on over 20 computers. 
We use OS X and Windows based computers.

I have tried the following:

#### OS X

- WebDesktop 2.5 - best performance so far.
- Fluid - able to be closed easy
- MachDesktop - not able to edit the URL 'window' after added once

#### Windows

- Active Desktop Gadget - Too many bugs
- MiniBrowser Gadger - Best performance, but too many bugs with the gadgets and a vulnerability
- BGinfo - not supporting "load from URL"
- AveDesktopSites2 - Runs, but I couldn't manage to see the loaded object(picture or whatever else I tried)... it was only showing as small square in the AveDesktop's settings window.

#### Cross-platform

- Snippage - able to be closed easily and hides when when showing desktop

Is there any other solution for me? It doesn't necessary need to be Active Desktop software. Could be a Company Info software that can load data from URL and to be not just as background on all computers – that's why I am looking for Mac and Windows versions - if possible to be "same brand" for Mac and Windows (like Snippage), so the settings are same in Mac and Windows.

---

**Note:**

Well I am sorry if you understand it that way, but non of these from above are working solutions for me. I am describing them so it's easier for the people to know what I have tried and what isn't working.

I don't think I am looking for **"anything else"**, I am looking for a solution.

Under **"anything else"** I understand that I already have a previous solution, but unfortunately I don't.

Comment: I've moved this here because a question like this would not be acceptable for [SU].

Comment: Well...
I don't think I am looking for "anything else", I am looking for a working solution.

I am sorry if you understand it that way, but non of these from above are working solutions for me. I am describing them to be easier for the people to know what I have tried and it isn't working.

Under "anything else" I understand that I already have a previous working solution, but unfortunately I don't.

Comment: Why is `BGInfo \\server\share\config.bgi` not an option? What is an URL for you? HTTP?

Comment: That was my thought too. Can you force everyone to set a network drive and refer to the image using that? i.e. X:\company_info.bmp

Answer (score 3):

[BGINFO4X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bginfo4x/) is a BGinfo clone for  **Windows**, **MacOSX**, Linux, BSD, UNIX, embeddeds (ARM,Raspberry).

It has many features, but those that seem to apply to you are:

- Highly Customizable: configure easily any setting of the program.
- Dynamic Data: the information is not static. Refreshed it with a configurable timer.
- Modular System: designed as a modular system, you can use different modules.
- Out Module: write any information. Use bash, powershell, wmi, vbs, perl, python, snmp, ....
- Script Module: execute any script or program, such as as sending an email with the result.
- Personalized Header: use a personalized header with your preferred message.
- Corporate Logo: use a a corporate logo or use your personalized one.
- Additional Image: add a personalized image or encrust a performance graphic.
- Corporate Wallpaper: force the use of a corporate wallpaper.

Find more info at [the Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/bginfo4x/wiki/BGINFO4X/).

Wah! You don't ask for it, but it can even tail a file. I am going to do some serious playing around with this thing! Mayer code me a few modules ...

Obligatory screenshot follows. There are more on SourceForge.

[image]